# custom error page for exceptions in mvc c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

### I have been searching for articles where i can customize my error page depending on the exception in my aplication.I tried the below method

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int status, Exception error)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = status;
        ViewBag.status = status;
        return View(status);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

---

### global.asax

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    Server.ClearError();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");

    if (ex.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
    {
        var httpException = (HttpException)ex;
        var code = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        routeData.Values.Add("status", code);
    }
    else
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("status", 500);
    }

    routeData.Values.Add("error", ex);

    IController errorController = new trialerror.Controllers.ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    { // this is important, because the 401 is not an error by default!!!
        throw new HttpException(401, "You are not authorised");
    }
}
```

---

### index.cshtml

```
 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        @{
            int x=ViewBag.status;

        }

            <p style=" color: Red;">
            @switch (x) {
                case 401: {
                        <span>PAGE NOT FOUND</span>
                    }
                    break;
                case 403: {
                        <span>FORBIDDEN</span>
                    }
                    break;
                case 404: {
                        <span>We have experienced a 404 error.Site temporarily down</span>
                    }
                    break;
                case 500: {
                        <span>please refresh page and try again!</span>
                    }
                    break;
                //and more cases for more error-codes...
                default: {
                        <span>Unknown error!!!</span>
                    }
                    break;
            }
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

The code can give customized page for all the errors in cases .But now i want to catch all exceptions from try -catch method like db exceptions and display it in a customized way.

example : "null value exception or connection string exceptions" .

My doubt is how can I give the case o something for that. I have no idea to continue?

Answer (score 0):

> But now i want to catch all exceptions from try -catch method like db exceptions and display it in a customized way

Two options:

1. Let the exceptions escape (`throw` without arguments in a `catch` will rethrow the same exception), and follow through the normal route for otherwise unhanded exceptions.
2. Redirect, as for any other controller/action to `ErrorController.Action`

#2 leaves the issue of passing the exception object to the controller (which will need a different code path in the error controller to pick up the two methods the `Exception` instance is passed), so #1 is generally the easier option.